# A serious bug in mathematica 11.2 during meshing in FEM modul

Tags: bugs, mesh, finite-element-method

I realised that in the new version of mathematica (11.2.) there is a problem with boundary meshing. If I set the MeshOrder=2 the meshing procedure doesn't recognise the boundary elements between two phases. Somehow lot of elements are not considered as boundary elements. This is quite problematic when i have to apply plane forces to the boundaries.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
sphere = 
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
ImplicitRegion[(x - 5)^2 + (y - 5)^2 + (z - 5)^2 >= 7, {x, y, 
 z}], {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}}];
ym3D = ToElementMesh[sphere, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
"RegionMarker" -> {{5, 5, 5}, 1}]
Show[ym3D["Wireframe"[PlotRange -> {All, {1, 7}, All}]]]
```

[image]

If i set the MeshOrder=1 than everything works well.

```
ym3D1 = ToElementMesh[sphere, "RegionHoles" -> None, "MeshOrder" -> 1, 
"RegionMarker" -> {{5, 5, 5}, 1}]
Show[ym3D1["Wireframe"[PlotRange -> {All, {1, 7}, All}]]]
```

[image]

I didn't have this problem in the previous version of Mathematica (11.0.) Can anybody help me how to avoid this problem/bug?

FYI: The whole region have to be meshed

```
ym3D["Wireframe"[
"MeshElement" -> "MeshElements",
"MeshElementStyle" -> {Directive[FaceForm[Green]], 
Directive[FaceForm[Red]]}, PlotRange -> {All, {5, 10.1}, All}]]
```

[image]

Comment: 3Drm is not a valid symbol name.

Comment: How avoid: Use MMA 11 or MMA 11.2 with option: `"MeshOrder" -> 1`. Or wait for MMA 11.3.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk Just in MMA 11.2 i dont need to use boundaryMarkerFunction because program automatically number the interfaces while in MMA 11 every boundary has a marker 0. So if this meshing worked in MMA 11.2 my work would be much easier.

Comment: Yes, this is an unfortunate bug in 11.2 and I am sorry about that. It is fixed in current sources and will be available in the next release. What is even more unfortunate is that I can not think of a workaround for V11.2 - So your best bet in this case is to say with 11.1 if you can or use "MeshOrder"->1. I apologize for that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed in Version 11.3:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
sphere = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
   ImplicitRegion[(x - 5)^2 + (y - 5)^2 + (z - 5)^2 >= 7, {x, y, 
     z}], {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}}];
ym3D = ToElementMesh[sphere, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{5, 5, 5}, 1}];
Show[ym3D["Wireframe"[PlotRange -> {All, {1, 8}, All}]]]
```

[image]

```
ym3D["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "MeshElements", 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> {Directive[FaceForm[Green]], 
    Directive[FaceForm[Red]]}, PlotRange -> {All, {5, 10.1}, All}]]
```

[image]